# Running a simple Python code on a Django created Website

Tags: python, html, django

So first of all, im pretty new to the world of programming. I started learning Python and i wrote a piece of code which takes some user input and outputs a url to an image. I want to integrate this to a website, so i started reading about Django and i managed to install and run a Django App. Now I am stuck at how to create this website which should simply take a user input, send it to my Python code, take the returned URL and display the image of that URL. Thanks!!!

EDIT:
so here is my Code i want to implement:

```
igpage = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/" + 
input("username: ") +"/")


htmlcode =  str((igpage.read()))
stelle =  (htmlcode.find("logging_page_id"))

g= 15

while str.isdigit(htmlcode[stelle+ 30 + g]) == False:
    g-=1

userid = (htmlcode[stelle+30:stelle+30+g+1])


igapi = "https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/users/"+ userid + "/info/"

igapipage = urllib.request.urlopen(igapi)

igapipagehtml = str(igapipage.read())

string = igapipagehtml

result = re.search('{"height": 1080, "url": "(.*)", "width": 1080}',string)

result2 = re.search('hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "(.*)", "width": 
1080, "height": 1080}',string)

result3 = re.search('hd_profile_pic_url_info": {"url": "(.*)", 
"width"',string)

result41 = re.search('hd_profile_pic_url_info":(.*)width"',string)

result42 = re.search('url": "(.*)"',result41.group(1))

if result != None:
    print (result.group(1))

elif result2 != None:
    print (result2.group(1))

elif result3 != None:
    print (result3.group(1))

elif result42 != None:
    print (result42.group(1))

else:
    print ("ERROR")`
```

Comment:
Purpose of this "Code" is to take a instagram username and spit out the HD Profile Picture. Not very professional i know, but just a small project to start learning to code.

Please don't judge my code too badly as it is one of my first ever written.

Thank you very much SO Community!

Comment: You've already got one close vote as too broad, and i would tend to agree with that voter. Please add a bit of specific information, for example adding the it of code you speak of would go a long way in improving this question. And then hopefully you will get useful answers

Comment: Thank you! I added it. Hope i still get some serious answers although the purpose of my code is more recreational.

Comment: Maybe using Django is the wrong approach here. But as i am a Beginner i absolutely don't know and my research didn't help me either honestly.